# Test image for upload with large file size

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file, jpeg, filesize

I have a ASP.NET MVC page site that needs file upload size verification for image files. 
I allow jpeg, jpg, bmp, png and gif files to be uploaded, and i can check their extension via upload form. What i need is image file (any extension) to validate the file size.

I need to make a jpeg file that exceeds 40kb in file size.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `imageFile` is an instance of `HttpPostedFileBase` or `HttpPostedFile`, you can use the `ContentLength` property to determine the size

```
  int KBSize = (imageFile.ContentLength / 1024);  //size in KiloBytes
  if(KBSize > 40)
  {
  }
  else
  {

  }
```

Hope that helps